# Linux VirtualBox Appliance with size less than 1GB

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine

For a lesson I once had in university I was given a VirtualBox appliance of a size of about 500MB with a fully working Debian with desktop environment and all.

I tried to simply do the same: Create a new machine in VirtualBox, use an automatically resizing VDI as a virtual hard drive and then simply run the Debian net installer ISO on it, installing a simple Debian system on the virtual disk and create an appliance out of the resulting machine.

What I get is a file of 2.7GB size. That is too much to distribute it in the use case I have.

I am looking for a way to create a small linux-vm image that I can distribute to a bunch of users without much linux experience. Subquestions to answer are:

Is there a better distribution to get a small image size?

Should I change something in the installing phase?

Are there VirtualBox options I can use to reduce the size of an appliance?

Comment: I think your question is too broad and will attract low-quality answers. Do you need a small VM or do you want to know how to create one? If you just need one, the question is off-topic ([we don't do product recommendations](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)). If you want to get some clues on creating such small images, please [edit] the question and explicitly say that you're not asking for prebuilt software, but for guide on creating slim VMs.

Comment: I now explicity ask for a way to create a small linux-vm image/appliance.

Comment: [DamnSmallLinux](http://damnsmalllinux.org) has a tiny footprint but I don't know if it is actively maintained.

Comment: You'll be way ahead if you start with a lightweight OS.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution.  Some are based on Debian, if that's important, and people have already done the work of stripping them to a more minimal working version.

Answer (score 1):

There are small linux distros out there designed for this sort of thing, ranging from 1G to the lowest i know of at 11MB, here are the smallest ones i know of:

- TinyCore

comes with a choice of FLTK or FLWM environments and is only 16ish MB, you can also install CorePlus at about 106MB, i think both need a hard wire connection to the internet to start with though.

- Damn Small Linux

This is 50ish MB and can be completely held in memory, its only x86 though i think.

- Porteus

About 300MB and can work with  KDE, MATE, Cinnamon and Xfce environments, also x86 and 64bit ok.

- Absolute Linux

Just under 1G, a little over for 64 bit. IceWM interface, preinstalled firefox and libreoffice.

Anyway those are just some examples off the top of my head. you can get really small with linux if you want to. hell just think of the distros that get made for ARM processors.

Comment: Just re-looked at tinycore plus, it can in fact do wireless out of the box, nice!

Answer (score -1):

Try Puppy Linux or other specialized distros.